# Send forms within Tabs with mvc Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm developping a web site and I'm new to MVC, I'm using MVC4, in my code, I create a PartialView where I put 4 Tabs, each tab is a Partial view, I'm able to fill the 3 forms, all my combo box are filled correctly, my problem is to submit the content of the Tabs, since I have 3 forms I'm not able to submit the informations to my database, the submit button should be on the Main View .

I added BeginForm on Member.cshtml to encapsulate the Tabs and I added the submit at the end but when I click in submit and I see the content of the Model, all the value that I select from the combo or in the input fields are null.

Can you help me please it's been few days that I'm searching for a result without any success.

in my model I have : CommandLineItems

```
public class CommandLineItems
{
 public GeneralInfo CLGeneralInfo { get; set; }
 public GeneralColor CLGeneralColor { get; set; }
 public General1    CLGeneral1{ get; set; }
}
```

The Main View contains (Member.cshtml) :

```
@model WebApp.Models.CommandLineItems
<div id="Maintabs">
    <ul id="MyTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#GeneralTab">General info</a></li>
        <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ColorTab">Colors</a></li>
        <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab1" id="1" style="display: none">1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="GeneralTab">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CLGeneralInfo, "_GeneralInformation")
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="ColorTab">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CLGeneralColor, "_GeneralColorView")
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab1">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CLGeneral1, "1")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The General Tab View is:

```
@model WebApp.Models.GeneralInfo
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<section id="content">
    <form class="form_validation">
        <div class="span6">
            <label>PO</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PO)
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <label>Line</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Line)
        </div>
        <label>League </label>
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, WebApp.Models.TypeTypeList())
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
}
```

The Color Tab View:

```
@model WebApp.Models.GeneralColor
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <section id="content">
        <form class="form_validation">
                <div class="span4">
                    <label>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColorPants)</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ColorPants, Model.AllColors})

                </div>
                <!--2eme col-->
                <div class="span4">
                    <label>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColorShoes)</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ColorShoes,  Model.AllColors)
                </div>
        </form>
    </section>
}
```

I have the same Partial View with a BeginForm for CLGeneral1.

Thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048183/jquery-tabs-with-mvc4-content

Comment: Thanks Hadi' I'll try to aplply it